# How do I convert the following string array into a dynamic array? Also, how do I associate a layout with it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-spinner

I am trying to pull an array dynamically from an adapter class, which currently works fine for a spinner. I have to utilize similar code such that I can use the (R.id.item ), so it can pull dynamically the contents in the array through R.id.item. Here's what I am trying to say:
Current implementation:

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
listItems.add("Personal Cookies");
listItems.add("Shared Cookies");
final CharSequence[] items = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);
```

Here is what I have for dynamic spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, entries);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
setSpinnerAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I make use of this arrayadapter  such that I can not only include a layout within my list array, but also pull out the dynamic strings that I am getting from this array adapter?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very confusing. Is there a way you can rephrase it?

Comment: Let me try, I would like my strings to be pulled dynamically like I am doing for the spinner,through the array adapter, instead of me manually describing it as item1/item2 etc as in the first set of code. any clue?